# What will return `insert` on abort event?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I can't find what will happen when the insertion in DAO is failed? I have the next typical DAO:

```
interface BaseDao<T> {
    @Insert
    fun insert(obj: T): Long

    @Insert
    fun insert(vararg obj: T): Array<Long>
}
```

When I insert a new row, the DAO returns row's ID... BUT what will it return on `abort`? Will it throw an exception? Or return `-1`?

**P.S.** It sounds stupidly but I could find a nothing about this problem.

Comment: Maybe what you want can be found here https://sqlite.org/lang.html ? But at least with conflict https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html its straight forward.

Comment: @CmosBattery, I am not sure but I'll check... Thank you!